# Need to sum a,b,c, unless they equal 13,14,17,18,19

Tags: python

Here is my assignment:

> Given 3 int values, a b c, return their sum. However, if any of the values is a teen -- in the range 13..19 inclusive -- then that value counts as 0, except 15 and 16 do not count as a teens. Write a separate helper "def fix_teen(n):"that takes in an int value and returns that value fixed for the teen rule. In this way, you avoid repeating the teen code 3 times (i.e. "decomposition"). Define the helper below and at the same indent level as the main no_teen_sum().

Here is the only solution I could come up with:

```
excep = [13,14,17,18,19]

def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
  if a in excep and b in excep and c in excep:
    return 0
  elif a in excep and b in excep and c not in excep:
    return c
  elif b in excep and c in excep and a not in excep:
    return a
  elif a in excep and c in excep and b not in excep:
    return b
  elif a in excep and b not in excep and c not in excep:
    return b+c
  elif b in excep and a not in excep and c not in excep:
    return a+c
  elif c in excep and a not in excep and b not in excep:
    return a+b
  else:
    return a+b+c
```

Comment: Is this code Python?

Comment: yes is in python

Comment: Well tag the question as Python

Comment: The assignment tells you *exactly* what to do. Just write code according to it.

Comment: i'm a noob, still struggling with nested functions and decorators

Comment: You should be asking such questions at https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Never mind you are a noob. Just follow the white rabbit. Start from here: *Write a separate helper "def fix_teen(n):"that takes in an int value and returns that value fixed for the teen rule.*

Comment: you guys are damn harsh. i've been studying nested functions or a week. i hate being held up on a simple idea. i'm frustrated beyond belief. if this isn't the place for noobs, please tell me

Comment: It doesn't seem to need a nested function. Assignment says "Define the helper below and at the same indent level as the main no_teen_sum()" so it means it is another function at the same level as `no_teen_sum()` (`no_teen_sum()` would be unable to use the helper function if it would be nested but placed below all code of `no_teen_sum()`).

Comment: No worries. We even don't know Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just break down the assignment and implement it as it tells you. Let's try it part by part:

> Given 3 int values, a b c, return their sum. However, if any of the values is a teen -- in the range 13..19 inclusive -- then that value counts as 0, except 15 and 16 do not count as a teens.

You already understood this principle.

> Write a separate helper "def fix_teen(n):"that takes in an int value and returns that value fixed for the teen rule.

Go ahead and write that function. You already know how to test for a 'teen' value using `if` and how to `return` a value.

> In this way, you avoid repeating the teen code 3 times (i.e. "decomposition").

This is telling you to actually *call* `fix_teen` three times and explains that it's good because you won't repeat yourself = implement one thing only once.

> Define the helper below and at the same indent level as the main no_teen_sum().

Now just implement `no_teen_sum` with the use of `fix_teen`. How? Call it for each of the three inputs to adjust the value being added up to the result.

---

*The actual implementation is left to the OP as an exercise.*

Comment: so i can call a function that is below another function? they do not need to be nested?

Comment: They don't. Yes, you can.

Comment: And whenever you hesitate, just try it ;)

Comment: excep = [13,14,17,18,19]

def no_teen_sum(a, b, c):
  return fix_num(a) + fix_num(b) +fix_num(c)
  
def fix_num(n):
  if n in excep:
    return 0
  else:
    return n